# Mean of each row of data.frames column nested in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have many data.frames nested in a list and want to get the row means of a column in the data.frames. Here is my MWE. I am wondering how to accomplish this in R?

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10))
ls1 <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
ls1

$df1
            x
1   0.5855288
2   0.7094660
3  -0.1093033
4  -0.4534972
5   0.6058875
6  -1.8179560
7   0.6300986
8  -0.2761841
9  -0.2841597
10 -0.9193220

$df2
            x
1  -0.1162478
2   1.8173120
3   0.3706279
4   0.5202165
5  -0.7505320
6   0.8168998
7  -0.8863575
8  -0.3315776
9   1.1207127
10  0.2987237
```

Something like this one

```
(ls1$df1+ls1$df2)/2


    x
1   0.23464051
2   1.26338903
3   0.13066227
4   0.03335964
5  -0.07232227
6  -0.50052806
7  -0.12812949
8  -0.30388085
9   0.41827645
10 -0.31029915
```

**Edited**

```
ls1 <- list(df=df1)
ls2 <- list(df=df2)
```

How this `(ls1$df+ls2$df)/2` can be written more coherently?

```
             x
1   0.23464051
2   1.26338903
3   0.13066227
4   0.03335964
5  -0.07232227
6  -0.50052806
7  -0.12812949
8  -0.30388085
9   0.41827645
10 -0.31029915
```

Comment: What's your desired output? What do you mean with the row means of one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the column, `cbind` the data.frames, and calculate the row means:

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(ls1, "[", "x")))
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland for your helpful answer. How about this one when two data.frames are in different lists `ls1 <- list(df=df1)`
`ls2 <- list(df=df2)`?

Comment: Combine the lists: `c(ls1, ls2)`. Or extract the data.frames from the lists.

Comment: Have many and variable number of `lists` from the output of `replicate`.

Comment: Well, how come? This seems like something you should fix. You seem to have not fully described your question.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no `NA` values, another option would be to do element wise (`+`) with `Reduce` and divide by the `length` of 'ls1'

```
Reduce(`+`, ls1)/length(ls1)
#            x
#1   0.23464051
#2   1.26338903
#3   0.13066227
#4   0.03335964
#5  -0.07232227
#6  -0.50052806
#7  -0.12812949
#8  -0.30388085
#9   0.41827645
#10 -0.31029915
```